# Как можно упростить код

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть 2 небольших вопроса для знатоков:

**1**

Есть вот такой вот ужасный код:

```
create_digit_button("1").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="wens")
create_digit_button("2").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="wens")
create_digit_button("3").grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="wens")
create_digit_button("4").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="wens")
create_digit_button("5").grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="wens")
create_digit_button("6").grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="wens")
create_digit_button("7").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="wens")
create_digit_button("8").grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="wens")
create_digit_button("9").grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="wens")
create_digit_button("0").grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="wens")
```

Можно ли как то элегантно сократить его до разумных пределов? Нужно ли это? Использовать 3 цикла и прочее кажется мне не лучшим решением, но и другого в голову ничего не лезет :(
Последняя строка явно выпадает, но как быть с предыдущими.

**2**

Есть обработчик событий:

```
def press_key(event: str) -> None:
    if event.char.isdigit():
        add_digit(event.char)
    elif event.char in OPERATIONS:
        add_operation(event.char)
    elif event.char == "`":
        calculate()
```

В последнем элифе `elif event.char == "\r":` я пытаюсь обработать нажатие 'return' на маке, однако, почему-то, оно на него не реагирует, как и на другие клавиши типа 'control', 'shift' etc.
Собственно, как я могу обработать нажатие клавиши 'return' на макбук?

Comment: Что касается обработки нажатия клавиши ‘return’ на макбуке, то вы можете использовать event.keysym вместо event.char

Comment: for i in range(1, 10):
    create_digit_button(str(i)).grid(row=(i-1)//3+1, column=(i-1)%3, sticky="wens")
create_digit_button("0").grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="wens")

1 код замени - смысл тот же

Comment: Не задавайте несколько вопросов в одном.

Comment: Это невероятно. Спасибо, огромное :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(3):
        digit = str((i-1)*3 + j+1) if i < 4 else "0"
        create_digit_button(digit).grid(row=i, column=j, columnspan=1 if digit != "0" else 2, sticky="wens")
```